# Stack implementation based on arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

Here is my code, but there is a one problem which I cannot understand: every time when I push an integer in my stack, the rest of (unfilled part) stack is filled by `0` values. Please explain me what is my error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
private:
    int* base;
    int max_size;
    int top;

public:
    Stack(int size = 100)
    {
        base = new int[size];
        max_size = size;
        top = -1;
    }
    ~Stack()
    {
        delete[] base;
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        return top == -1;
    }

    bool full() const
    {
        return top == max_size - 1;
    }

    void push(int element)
    { 
        if (top == max_size-1) {
            cout<< "Stack overflow" << endl;
            return;
        }
        base[++top] = element; 
    }

    void pop()
    { 
        if(top == -1) {
            cout << "Stack underflow" << endl;
            return;
        } 
        top--; 
    }

    int & read_top() const
    {
        return base[top];
    }

    void print()
    {
        int i = 0 ;
        cout << "Stack is ";
        while(i <= max_size)
        {
            cout << base[i] <<" ";
            i++;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack first(10);
    for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        first.push(i*i);
        first.print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `print` displays element up to the capacity and not the size...

Comment: [OT]: You don't respect Rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: I ran your code, the stack filled with garbage at the beginning, and also the unfilled part filled with garbage after push. @Jarod42 is right, you should change your loop to print the relevant part. But nothing is wrong with your code, and the unfilled part is not have zeros in my machine...

Comment: What do you want them to be filled with?

Comment: here is my output:
Stack is 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 135233 
Stack is 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 135233 
Stack is 0 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 135233 
Stack is 0 1 4 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 135233 
Stack is 0 1 4 9 16 0 0 0 0 0 135233 
Stack is 0 1 4 9 16 25 0 0 0 0 135233

Comment: i just want to see only pushed elements

Comment: thank you very much for excellent explanation

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Stack s(10);
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++)
    s.push(i);
```

in `print` you have:

```
std::cout << "Stack is ";
while(i <= max_size)
    std::cout << base[i] << ' ';
```

in the above case, `s.max_size` is 10, so you are going to print the values for base[0,10), 5 of which are uninitialized. Because the app hasn't done much with memory yet, chances are you'll get a pristine (zeroed) memory block when you perform an allocation.

A possible variation of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std ;  // unlearn the habbit of doing this.
#include <memory>  // for unique_ptr

class Stack
{
    // note: class is private by default.
        // unique_ptr will automatically free memory for us.
        using  ptr_t = std::unique_ptr<int[]>;

        ptr_t  base_;
        int*   top_;
        int*   end_;

    public :
        Stack(int size=100)
          : base_(new int[size])
          , top_(base_.get())
          , end_(top_ + size)
        {}

        bool empty() const
        { return top_ == base_.get(); }

        bool full() const
        { return top_ == end_; }

        // don't print errors from a library
        bool push(int value)
        { 
            if (full())  // written in terms of our own members
                return false;
            *(top_++) = value;
            return true; 
        }

        bool pop()
        { 
            if (empty())  // written in terms of our own members
                return false;
            --top_;
            return true;
        }

        const int& read_top() const  // const ref so it's not modifiable
        { return *(top_-1); }

        int size() const { return end_ - top_; }
        int capacity() const { return end_ - base_.get(); }

        std::ostream& print(std::ostream& to)
        {
            to << "Stack is ";
            for (int* ptr = base_.get(); ptr != top_; ++ptr)
                to << *ptr << ' ';
            to << '\n';
            return to;
        }

        // or we could do this:
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& to, const Stack& s)
        {
            to << '[';
            for (int* ptr = s.base_.get(); ptr != s.top_; ++ptr) {
                to << *ptr << ',';
            }
            return to << ']';
        }
};

int main()
{
    Stack s(5);
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s.print(std::cout);
    std::cout << "stack is: " << s << '\n';
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/JsA4EU

Answer (score -2):

I'm not very sure I get your question right: what do you mean with "every time when I push an integer in my stack"? As far as I can see, you initialize your stack once and then do some pushes, without changing the undelying array in between. What happens here is that your array is initialized to 0 (don't count on your compiler to do it every time, but this time it does - most likely you are compiling without optimizations) and then you add single elements and, as somebody already answered, you don't print your stack only (that is, from 0 up to top), but the whole undelying array. If compiled optimized, you may get garbage values instead of zeroes (the array is not initialized to some initial vlaues in constructor and what is not assigned may contain any value). Hope it helps.

A bug in the code: in the `print()` method you should have `while(i < max_size)`

Comment: consider reformulating your answer to sound more like an answer, and less like an ongoing Q&A forum posts